# Testing sequence of REST API calls - "there was no current spec"

Tags: angular, rest, testing, observable

I am trying to test the sequence of create/delete for as REST-service. The example below always passes in the IDE, but gives an error in the Karma/Jasmine debugger.

```
"expect' was used when there was no current spec, 
this could be because an asynchronous test timed out"
```

Each test alone runs ok.

---

```js
it("should return the number of deleted items after creation", done => {
  const ex1 = sgformsService.getOrCreate("Endoskopie", 9999, "2019-03-20");
  const ex2 = sgformsService.deleteByParameter(
    "Endoskopie",
    9999,
    "2019-03-20"
  );
  const ex = ex2.pipe(concat(ex1)).subscribe((val: number) => {
    expect(val).toEqual(7);
    done();
  });
});
```

Comment: Would you be able to create a minimal working example? So it's possible to play around with the test a bit and resolve the problem? The error message could suggest, that the test is over before the actual expect within the subscribe was called.

Comment: Another problem could be that concat first emits the values of the first observable and then from the concated observable. That means, the expect(val) bit gets triggered twice in the current setup. Not too sure if that is intended. To help further it would be necessary to know what getOrCreate and deleteByParam returns. Is there a delay or anything like that involved?

Comment: Thanks for looking into it, @Erbsenkoenig. See below. I needed some more debugging to understand how the values are returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had not fully understood how the values are returned, and expected that only the last would be returned. Here is the working solution:

```
 it('should return the number of deleted items after creation', done => {
      const ex1 = sgformsService.getOrCreate('Endoskopie', 9999, '2019-03-20')
      const ex2 = sgformsService.deleteByParameter('Endoskopie', 9999, '2019-03-20')
      const ex= ex1.pipe(concat(ex2))
        .subscribe((val: number|SgformsBase[]) => {
          if (typeof(val) === "number") {
            expect(val).toEqual(7)
            done()
          }
      });
  })
```

Comment: but if you are only interested in the value emitted by the deleteByarameter you could use the flatMap operator then you wouldn't need to check for type and you wouldn't run through the method twice.